# Are the values from a serial column guaranteed to match the insertion order if the column is added to populated PostgreSQL table?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have been looking into adding a serial column to an existing table whic does have a `created_at` column.

On the first sight the ordering between the `created_at` and the serial column seems to match but upon further inspection some mismatches can be spotted.

While these outliers could easily be attributed to the fact the host does not have a reliable date/time source (which is the reason I'm adding a serial column after all), I could not find anything describing the expected behaviour of the sequence generator in this specific case.

Comment: No, there is no such guarantee. The order can be wrong due to sequence value caching or rollbacks (probably a lot other things as well)

Comment: and what is the value of `created_at` column ? For example now() function returns start time of current transaction, not current date time (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

Answer (score 0):

That is never guaranteed.

Sequence values are dealt out in the order of the calls to the `nextval` function. Now if two of these statements run concurrently:

```
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (nextval('seq'));
```

Each of them does the following:

- call the `nextval` function
- insert a row into the table
- commit the transaction

Now it could happen that the first statement calls `nextval` first, but the second statement performs the insert and commit first, by a very narrow margin.

Now nothing keeps you from *defining* that the order of the rows is determined by the sequence value, so the actual order of inserts need not matter.

Things become more difficult if the sequence was defined using a `CACHE` value greater than 1. Then each session fetches more than one sequence value at the same time, and the next few calls to `nextval` are satisfied using these cached values, without actually calling the sequence. That can of course disturb the order even more, so you might want to avoid cached sequence values if you want the generated value to roughly correspond to the order of insertion.