# Different order for nextval() of sequence and now() timestamp on concurrent insert queries in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

I have a table with the below columns

```
CREATE Table SeqTest 
(
    Id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    StartTime TIMESTAMP NULL,
    StartTimeID BIGINT NULL
);
```

I have a sequence created using the below command

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seqtestid_seq;
```

Insert query

```
INSERT INTO SeqTest (StartTime, StartTimeID) 
VALUES (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', NEXTVAL('seqtestid_seq'));
```

Output of the query when tested concurrently

```
test_db=# SELECT * FROM SeqTest order by starttime asc;

 id  |         starttime          | starttimeid
-----+----------------------------+-------------
 309 | 2023-11-16 11:18:41.008201 |         409
 305 | 2023-11-16 11:18:41.008202 |         405
 307 | 2023-11-16 11:18:41.008222 |         407
 310 | 2023-11-16 11:18:41.008334 |         411
 308 | 2023-11-16 11:18:41.008337 |         408
 311 | 2023-11-16 11:18:41.008757 |         410
 304 | 2023-11-16 11:18:41.008762 |         404
 306 | 2023-11-16 11:18:41.008784 |         406
 312 | 2023-11-16 11:18:41.009812 |         412
```

while inserting concurrently to the table using different transactions, the order of the `StartTime` and `StartTimeID` differs. Is there any way I can make both columns in ascending order?

**UPDATE**

Here is how I'm inserting the records concurrently using a .NET Core console application in a `Parallel.ForEach` loop with `Dapper`

```cs
public static async Task TestSeqQuery()
{
    using (var conn = GetConnection())
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            string sql = @"INSERT INTO SeqTest (StartTime, StartTimeID) VALUES (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'utc', nextval('seqtestid_seq'));";
            var result = await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql, tran);

            tran.Commit();
        }

    }
}
...

Parallel.ForEachAsync(Enumerable.Range(0, 100), async (i, ct) =>
{
    await TestSeqQuery();

}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: You'll find both the reason behind this and a suggested solution [in the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html#id-1.9.3.81.7): *Because `nextval` and `setval` calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently.*

Comment: [PostgreSQL gapless sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984196/postgresql-gapless-sequences)

Comment: @Zegarek, Thanks for the quick update. The gap between the sequence numbers is okay in my case. The issue I'm facing is the difference in the order of the columns `StartTime` and `StartTimeID`. When I sort with the column `StartTime`, I'm getting the values of `StartTimeID`  without any order.

Comment: The gaps and the unexpected order are the same problem, caused by the same behaviour of PostgreSQL sequences, and both are solved the same way - you can find an example in Craig Ringer's answer I linked above. Also, be aware what exact point in time [`now()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) is referring to.

Comment: 1) The values of `id` roughly track those of `starttimeid` so however you are generating the INSERTs is consistent. It would be useful to add to your question your method for *...inserting concurrently ...* 2) `now()` grabs the time at the start of the transaction which maybe offset from when the INSERT is actually done and the `NEXTVAL('seqtestid_seq')` grabbed.

Comment: Your example statement is bad, because it will insert the same timestamp into all rows. But I think that I understand a problem, and it is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72687198/6464308), right?

Comment: I've missed mentioning how I insert concurrently to the table. I have updated it. The problem is similar to the question you have mentioned @LaurenzAlbe. The sequence cache is set as 1. Is there any way we can ensure the same order for both the `StartTime` and `StartTimeID` columns?

Comment: @Zegarek I have tried using a table with a counter column as mentioned in the other question. I'm doing the insert in a new transaction concurrently. The order of columns is still not the same. When I sort by `StartTime`, the `StartTimeID` is not having any order.

Comment: That is answered in the linked question. There is no way to guarantee the same ordering, except by serializing the transactions (no concurrency at all), which would be terrible for performance.